# Geometric interpretation of an elliptic point on a Riemann surface / hyperbolic surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\Gamma$ be a Fuchsian group of signature $[g;m_1,\dots,m_r;s]$.  When we quotient $\mathbb{H}^2$ by $\Gamma$ we obtain a genus $g$ surface with $s$ cusps and $r$ elliptic points with orders $m_1,\dots,m_r$.

Now, the concepts of genus and cusp have a geometric description i.e handles/holes and well, cusps.  What is the equivalent description of an elliptic point and what does it look like?

Comment: From the topological viewpoint or from the viewpoint of the theory of Riemann  surfaces, the "elliptic" (aka "orbifold") points are indistinguishable from the rest of the points of the quotient. You have to refine the structure (by considering the quotient singular Riemannian metric or, better, by think in terms of orbifolds) to see the difference.

Comment: Assume we adopt one of these viewpoints, say orbifolds, what can we say?

Comment: The we can say that these are precisely the singular points (also known as "orbifold points", "stacky points") of the quotient orbifold. I recommend reading the article by Peter Scott from 1983, "Geometry of 3-manifolds". For a brief introduction, see http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Kaye.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are sometimes called cone points, because they look like taking a piece of paper with a corner of angle $2\pi/m_i$ and folding it over to identify opposite sides of the vertex. This produces something which looks like a cone at the singular point. They are also sometimes called pillowcase points as they look like the corners of a pillow.

So, for example, if $m_i=2$ then take a piece of paper, pick a point on one side, and identify the sides opposite the point to make a cone. If $m_i=3$ take a piece with a $120^\circ$ angle and identify the opposite sides. The cone gets "sharper" as the angle decreases, i.e. as $m_i$ increases.